# How to install CMake on FreeBSD without Sphinx

Tags: freebsd, sphinx

CMake recently (September 2014 I guess) started to depend on py27-Sphinx port for its documentation. I actually don't use python on my server, but CMake builds and installs it and its 9 other dependencies just to build its documentation, even though I chose not to build and/or install the documentation.

This is really annoying, have to keep 9 ports up to date just so CMake can build its own documentation that I won't ever read.

I can't get rid of the CMake, as it is needed to build mysql. I just want to get rid of the Sphinx and its dependencies. All help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is a patch for this: https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=193259 Unfortunately it is not committed for a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured this out thanks to @citrin's comment.

Adam Weinberger reported this as a bug [here](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=193259).
He also provided two patches for two different desirable options: pre-building the man pages, or building cmake without them. I opted for the latter one.

The attachment [here](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=146691&action=edit) includes little fixes to the Makefile and pkg-plist of the corresponding port. I just updated my cmake Makefile and pkg-plist with the new lines, and voila! There was another config option for manpages, and after I chose not to build with manpages, the dependency disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest port of cmake you can de-select building the man-pages and sphinx will not get pulled in.

```
cd /usr/ports/devel/cmake
make config
```

I had the same issue.